# How to convert Square FT (in.) to Square FT (ft)?

Tags: measurements

I apologize for the confusing question title. I work with area rugs, and have almost never done measurements before. I am tasked with converting these measurements into the right unit.

I have four measurements:

6

19

39

81

These are all in Square Inches I believe. On the spreadsheet it shows "Square Footage (in.)"

I need to convert them to Square FT. I'm unfamiliar with measurements, but is it any different than regular inches? Would 6 square inches be 0.5 square ft?

Thank you.

EDIT: Some were saying the question is confusing, I agree. If it helps, here is the product width for each of these measurements.

6 = 24 inches wide

19 = 31 inches wide

39 = 63 inches wide

81 = 94 inches wide

I really wish I could provide more information, but I am just as confused on the entire thing as anyone else.

Comment: Well 6 square inches is about the size of a credit card, so that's a rather small rug. At the moment, I can't make any sense of the question.

Comment: It's a squared relationship so it's a bit different.  6 square inches would only be 3 inches by 2 inches.  You would need 12 of them to make 0.5 square feet.  1 foot is 12 inches, so 1 square foot is 12x12 = 144 square inches.

Comment: Can you also find (or guess from photos) the lengths of these rugs? 6 sq FEET 24" wide would be 3 feet long (36"). 19 sq feet (31" wide) would be just over 7 feet long. 39 sq feet (63" wide) would be the same length, and 81sq ft 94" wide would be about 10 feet long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's think about how we work out the area in inches. What we are simply doing is multiplying the lengths (in inches) of the shape (let's say rectangle for simplicity) to get the square footage. ie.

$$a * b = area_{inches}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are sides of the rectange (measured in inches).

Instead of using the length of the sides in feet, we could convert it into inches first. Given that there are 12 inches in a foot (or $1/12$ feet in an inch):

$$\frac a  {12} * \frac b  {12} = area_{feet}$$
$$ { a * b \over 144} = area_{feet}$$

---

This can also be derived from the units, we can treat the units as an equation themselves.

$$ feet = {{inches} \over 12} $$
$$ feet^2 = ({{inches} \over 12})^2 $$
$$ feet^2 = {{inches}^2 \over 12^2} $$

This sort of logic can be used for any unit conversations. Given the relationship of the base units (in this case inches and feet), more complicated relationships can be worked out.

---

For example, using your 81 square inch measurement. If we replace the ${inches}^2$ with $81$, we get 81 inches squared in square feet

$$ feet^2 = {81 \over 12^2} $$
$$ feet^2 = 0.5625 $$

Comment: I appreciate that very much. In all honesty though, I wouldn't have the slightest clue on how to plug in my measurements to those equations to derive an answer.

Comment: @DigitalWalrus I realised a made a mistake in the second equation. It should be more clear now. You have the $inches^2$ numbers (ie. 6, 19, 39, 81). Simply replace the $inches^2$ in the last line of the second equation with those numbers. I've added an example at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! I have attempted to calculate the figures, let me know if they look right.

Comment: 6 = 0.25  19 = 3  39 = 11  81 = 46

Comment: @DigitalWalrus Be careful, you have swapped your original numbers with the $feet$ term, not $feet^2$. Look at the example I put in the question, note how I am not squaring 81 (the square is part of the original numbers you have)

Comment: Alright, my bad on that. Does that mean the 6 Sq. Inches will be 0.04 Sq. Feet?

Comment: @DigitalWalrus Exactly, nicely done

Comment: Thanks, I emailed it back to them, hopefully I did everything correctly. I appreciate the help.